# Adjust view size in UIViewController like the UITableViewController did

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

By default, when a UINavigationController pushes a UIViewController, the height of view of UIViewController is set to full screen height. But when the UITableViewController is pushed, the tableview automatically adjusts its size to fit the remain space of the screen instead of setting its height to fullscreen. I wonder how the UITableViewController do this magic.

What code should I put inside the UIViewController so that the view of UIViewController behave like the tableview of the UITableViewController(view height auto fit screen)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any scrollView like tableView in navigationController will have a 64px offset, but the size won't be changed. If set a property of viewController:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Default this property is YES, If it is NO, the tableView will not have the offset and behaves like normal controller.

Comment: If I set navigation bar translucent to false and add a tableview inside a uiviewcontroller as the only subview of the view, am I able to set the view height equal to the height of the tableview inside the UITableViewController? And also I don't want to add any container view to the uiviewcontrollser's view.

Comment: I have changed the controller's root view's width in 'loadView' function with the code: self.view.frame.size.width += PicMargin;